# gitlab job succesfull when the job not finished

Tags: gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

[image: runner output]
I'm using a runner to build a docker image, and the job was marked succeeded before the end of dockerfile.

Someone  known what is happened ?

the job was finished when I have retry the pipeline
[image]

Comment: can you edit your question to add the dockerfile?

Comment: I had similar issues (not exactly the same) with non-printable chars in docker file.
And / or in .gitlab-ci.yml file

Comment: thank you, but after this issues, the pipeline work correctly without any change(because it finished with  retry button on gitlab interface). So I think it's not a problem with non-printable chars.